# Pandas: More Efficient .map() function or method?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a rather large dataset of ~37 million data points that are hierarchically indexed into three categories country, productcode, year. The country variable (which is the countryname) is rather messy data consisting of items such as: 'Austral' which represents 'Australia'. I have built a simple guess_country() that matches letters to words, and returns a best guess and confidence interval from a known list of country_names. Given the length of the data and the nature of hierarchy it is very inefficient to use .map() to the Series: country. [The guess_country function takes ~2ms / request]

My question is: Is there a more efficient .map() which takes the Series and performs map on only unique values? (Given there are a LOT of repeated countrynames)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't, but if you want to only apply to unique values, just do that yourself.  Get `mySeries.unique()`, then use your function to pre-calculate the mapped alternatives for those unique values and create a dictionary with the resulting mappings.  Then use pandas `map` with the dictionary.  This should be about as fast as you can expect.

Comment: Alternatively: build a cache into `guess_country` itself, by making a dictionary `_country_guesses` mapping inputs to return values, and checking that it's in the dictionary first, and filling with the result if not. Should be similar, but makes it work for mapping multiple tables and so on transparently.

Comment: That would work well! ... just thought of another solution also, which is in-place replacement of the Hierarchical Index when Country is Level 0

Comment: Memoizing `guess_country` will certainly speed it up, but over 30 million data points it may be perceptibly slower than creating a dictionary.  Even if you memoize `guess_country`, `map` will still call it for every single point, which means you suffer the extra function call overhead every time.  By precalculating unique values and only calling the function on those, you limit the function call overhead to only the number of unique values.  Whether the difference matters will likely depend on how many distinct values you have.

Comment: Also a good idea re: Cache to improve the country_guess() function performance. I currently check correct spellings first (using a dictionary lookup) which is very quick. But I hadn't considered adding returned 'best_guesses' to this check.

Comment: However running the function on unique data will make the cache redundant.

Answer (score 0):

On Solution is to make use of the Hierarchical Indexing in DataFrame!

```
data = data.set_index(keys=['COUNTRY', 'PRODUCTCODE', 'YEAR'])
data.index.levels[0] = pd.Index(data.index.levels[0].map(lambda x: guess_country(x, country_names)[0]))
```

This works well ... by replacing the data.index.levels[0] -> when COUNTRY is level 0 in the index, replacement then which propagates through the data model.

Answer (score 0):

Call `guess_country()` on unique country names, and make a `country_map` Series object with the original name as the index, converted name as the value. Then you can use `country_map[df.country]` to do the conversion.

```
import pandas as pd
c = ["abc","abc","ade","ade","ccc","bdc","bxy","ccc","ccx","ccb","ccx"]
v = range(len(c))
df = pd.DataFrame({"country":c, "data":v})

def guess_country(c):
    return c[0]

uc = df.country.unique()
country_map = pd.Series(list(map(guess_country, uc)), index=uc)
df["country_id"] = country_map[df.country].values
print(df)
```